# Comparador web con Python Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, scraping

Hola gente soy nuevo en esto y me disculpo si no me especifico bien. Estoy aprendiendo sobre **Web Scraping** y sobre el automatizador **Selenium**. Mi idea es hacer un comparador de costos de transporte de mercaderia. Para ello, mi sistema tendría que ingresar en las paginas de todas las empresas, completar los campos correspondientes a las localidades, peso y dimension; recoger los datos que estas arrojan y volvarlos en mi sitio web. Mi pregunta es Selenium + web scraping es la opcion ideal o existen otras tecnicas/modulos para hacerlo. Muchas gracias.

Comment: Te recomendaría que hicieras un curso online, o que leas algún libro al respecto de como se hace con Python. No es un tema sencillo, pero en un par de semanas puedes dedicándole horas todos los días. Podrías tener una idea de hacer scrapping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hay varias librerías para hacer scraping, te hago un breve resumen.

- Request: Para empezar y hacer cosas rápidas
- Beautifulsoup: una librería más avanzada que request que permite hacer extracciones y limpiezas de manera sencillaa
- Scrapy: Para hacer proyectos de scrapping más grandes
- Selenium: se puede combinar con las anteriores o usarla sola, se diferencia de las otras dos en que puede renderizar los elementos Java.
- Splash: al igual que Selenium, permite renderizar el Java y Flash

Una vez hecha esta introducción, respondiendo a tu pregunta, **no hay una opción ideal.** Todo dependerá de las características de tu proyecto y de tu manejo con cada librería

Comment: Gracias por la informacion!

Comment: @MaxSchwab de nada :) , pero si consideras que tanto la respuesta de Ruben como la mía son buenas, la mejor forma de dar las gracias en Stackoverflow, es darle un punto positivo a la respuesta, y porque no, si es la respuesta que buscabas, marcar una de las dos como respuesta a la pregunta.

Answer (score 0):

en principio con Selenium puedes scrapear y hacer perfectamente esto que necesitas. ¿Hay formas mejores?, puede ser, podrías mirar librerías como **BeautifullSoup + requests**, o algunas otras que hay, pero en general, si ya conoces Selenium puedes ir con ella.

Tu problema principal es que, si tienes muchas webs y todas ellas distintas, tendrás que programar el scraping para cada una de ellas, tanto la cumplimentación del formulario como la extracción del dato, pero supongo que en este sentido no te estoy diciendo nada nuevo.

Así que en definitiva, con tanto curro delante, si te sientes cómodo con Selenium, continua con el, en otro caso seguramente perderás más tiempo aprendiendo y haciendo pruebas que el beneficio real que te daría otra herramienta.

Espero que esto te pueda ayudar!

Comment: Muchas gracias!